# Django Class based views and Simple Image Upload

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

When trying out a simple image upload I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError at /upload/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

Here are the snippits of relevant code (If you need more, let me know!):

```
# Models

class Photo(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/'+str(uuid.uuid4())+'/')

# Views

class PhotoUploadView(CreateView):
    model = Photo
    form_class = PhotoUploadForm
    template_name = 'upload.html'
    success_url = '/thanks/'

# Forms

class PhotoUploadForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=255)

# Urls

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^upload/', views.PhotoUploadView.as_view()),
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting an exception because you've specified a "model" attribute in your View class which implements the [SingleObjectMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#singleobjectmixin). However, you're not giving it an instance of your Photo model to render.

Since you just want to create a new photo, you should remove the model attribute from your View class:

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from myapp.forms import PhotoUploadModelForm

class PhotoUploadView(CreateView):
    form_class = PhotoUploadModelForm
    template_name = 'upload.html'
    success_url = '/thanks/'
```

And modify your form class to inherit from a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform):

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from myapp.models import Photo

class PhotoUploadModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['image', 'title']
```

Comment: Just to be sure I understand.

The above code belongs in the models.py file, and I should remove the model = Photo from the view?

Comment: Best practice is to create a forms.py file, and put all your forms there. See updated answer.